# Check if PictureBox is empty

Tags: vb.net, picturebox

I have a simple program where the user needs to input an image and other info, e.g. Lname, Fname, etc. Then I need the data that will be saved really contains the `Image` in the `PictureBox`.

I have tried this in an `If` statement:

```
picturebox1.image = nothing
```

but of course it wont work. I don't know the codes to prevent the user save the data without the Image

```
If tbLName.Text = "" Or
   tbFName.Text = "" Or
   picturebox1.image = Nothing or
   cbCategory.SelectedIndex = -1 Then
    MessageBox.Show("Input data to Update", "Update", 
    MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    Return            
End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
picturebox1.image Is Nothing
```

Comment: no prob kabayan.. good luck!  shift ka na pala sa C#.  Walang career dyan sa vb.net.

Comment: thesis ko palang bro haha pero noted.

Comment: ic.  well thesis ko vb6 so pwede ka pa naman mag shift lol.. good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all don't assign the picture file to the BackgroundImage property of PictureBox1, instead assign the picture image to ImageLocation property of PictureBox1. You can set this in property window at design time or in run-time you can assign by **PictureBox1.ImageLocation = "Full image path\images.png"**.
Now you can check by following code.
if PictureBox1.ImageLocation="" then
   No image
else
   image exists
end if